# How to fix problem with React-Redux(mapDispatchToProps() in Connect() must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I ported my application to redux-thunk and the error started to appear in the console(
mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(UsersContainer) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.).
But with the appearance of this error, nothing has changed. How to fix it?

Reducer:

```
import {getTeamApi} from "./api";

let date = {
    teamDate: []
};
const realtorsDate = (state = date, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GetTeam":
            return {...state, teamDate: [...state.teamDate, ...action.team]};
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export let GetTeam = (team) => ({
    type: "GetTeam",
    team
})
export default realtorsDate;
export const getTeamThunks = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        getTeamApi.then(response => {
            dispatch(GetTeam(response.items));
        });
    }
}
```

Container component:

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {getTeamThunks} from "../../store/realtorsDate";
import ScrollableAnchor from "react-scrollable-anchor";
import MainFourth from "./main-fourth";
import Photo from "../../Images/pivo-3.jpg";
import React from "react";

class UsersContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <ScrollableAnchor id={"team"}>
                    <h2>Наша команда</h2>
                </ScrollableAnchor>
                <div className="MainFourth">
                    {this.props.realtorsDate.map((el, i) => (
                        <MainFourth key={i} el={el} Photo={Photo}></MainFourth>))}
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

let MapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        realtorsDate: state.realtorsDate.teamDate
    }
}
let FourthContainerBlock = connect(MapStateToProps, getTeamThunks)(UsersContainer)
export default FourthContainerBlock
```

Component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./../../css/App.css";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faAt, faMobileAlt} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
class MainFourth extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="team" key={this.props.i}>
            <div className="about-team">
                <h2 className="team-name">
                    {this.props.el.SecondName}&nbsp;
                    {this.props.el.Name}
                </h2>

                <h2 className="team-position">{this.props.el.Position}</h2>
                <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMobileAlt}></FontAwesomeIcon> : {this.props.el.Phone}</p>
                <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAt}></FontAwesomeIcon> : {this.props.el.Mail}</p>
            </div>
            <img className="TeamsPhoto" src={this.props.Photo} alt="" />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MainFourth;
```

Ty all

Comment: Shouldn't it be `getTeamApi()`, you need to call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually pretty straight forward, `getTeamThunks` should return a js object and that should be synchronous. You can do asynchronous things in the action creators.

The second argument to connect is simply used to map the dispatch to props(the reason why most tend to name it as such).

For example, `mapDispatchToProps` can look like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getTeamThunks: () => dispatch(actions.getTeamThunksData())
  }
}
let FourthContainerBlock = connect(MapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainer)
```

Now the `getTeamthunksData` can be written like this:

```
export const getTeamThunksData = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        getTeamApi.then(response => {
            dispatch(GetTeam(response.items));
        });
    }
}
```

In your component, you can dispatch it by using `this.props.getTeamThunks()`. Where you execute it depends on your requirements.